# The second follow up intent of my Dialogflow Agent can't catch the values of its parent parameters

Tags: parameters, dialogflow-es

I'm building a chatbot which is abled to advice books. So, I need to ask gender, title and author. For that I made the intent "search-book" :

[image]

Then, I made a follow-up intent "Yes_Author":

[image]

[image]

And the last is the follow-up intent "Yes_Author_Yes_Title":

[image]

[image]

When I try the conversation here are the responses :

[image]

[image]

[image]

and the third call didn't take the Gender and the Author from previous intents. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the three parameters, then you should have only one intent and collect the parameters in that only. Something like: [image]

Here `Name` and `Gender` are custom entities and for the title, I am using `@sys.any` (you need to extract title programmatically or use other alternatives).

Name entity
[image]

Gender entity
[image]

Please Note: capturing Non-English names have an issue right now. Also, you need to train the intent with proper examples to make it more effective.

Answer (score 0):

up intent(Yes_Author_Yes_Title)
under action and parameter value must be #search-author-Yes-followup.Gender and #search-author-Yes-followup.Author
Gender and Author must be entities taken from previous intent